I fail to register a close vote mentionning that the question is off-topic and should be migrated
When I try to register a close vote for this about any question as follows

close
off-topic because...
This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

the only choice that I have is "belongs on meta.crypto.stackexchange.com", which is inappropriate. That's what I see:

Update: I'm told I should see "a search box to type in another site and choose that", but it is nowhere that I can find it using FireFox 26.0 on Win-X64; I think I remember it was here at some earlier point in time.
That same issue happens in the review process.
Is it a bug? Else, what's the appropriate way?
Update: If instead of "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" I select "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)", I can register a close vote with an editable comment preset to "This question appears to be off-topic because it is about", but no migration request will be automatically processed.

Afaik you should see it.

@mikeazo: I fail to see what action I should perform to vote to close the question, stating that it is off-topic and belongs to, say, superuser. And I'm uncertain about what it refers to in your comment.

When I vote to close and choose that it belongs on another site, I get two options: belongs on meta and a search box to type in another site and choose that. That is what I think you should see. It is interesting that you don't have that option because if multiple people select that, the question will be automatically migrated when closed.

I asked a question on meta.SO recently because we were getting posts closed that said they belonged on another site but didn't migrate. Seeing your question makes me understand why they aren't getting migrated. Likely people are just typing in the reason "it belongs on X site". Maybe others aren't seeing the option to put in another site. Need to do some digging.

@mikeazo: I confirm that on the popup window reading like "Close>Off-topic>Migration", obtained after This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, I have no other option than belongs on meta.crypto.stackexchange.com, and that feels downright a bug, that would explain "getting posts closed that said they belonged on another site but didn't migrate". Seems to be the case for all questions, for some months perhaps. I'm currently using FireFox 26.0 on  Winx64, if that matters.

That search box is only visible to moderators, @mikeazo.

@Shog9: I think that I remember that I have seen this search box, though I was never a moderator (Update: now that I read your answer: perhaps it was on a non-beta site). And anyway, I'm following a logical path, but face a dead end.

Agree that the UI is not ideal here, but... It's what we got right now. I've provided work-around instructions in my answer - unless there are a high volume of such posts, I don't think this is really that much of an issue (and if there are a large number of them, there may be other issues...)

@mikeazo: As others have says, the reason you get that is that most of us aren't able to flag for migration so have to put suitable reasons and hope you send them over for us :P

@Shog9: In this recent discussion I tried to count them for a few months. We get a lot of posts that would be a better fit for Security.SE.

Normal users on non beta sites have the choice between 5 entries (not just meta). The search box is for diamond mods only.

This site is currently still in beta. We try to avoid creating migration paths to or from beta sites, so as to allow them to develop their own community with less concern for potential overlaps on other sites. 
That said, if you find a question that is wholly off-topic here but would make a good question for another site, flag it and select "other" - then type in the URL of the site you'd like it migrated to and why you think it should be migrated. A moderator handling the flag can migrate it then if need-be.

Do you think it might make sense to include a "flag for moderator attention" (or just "enter custom close reason") box also in the "closing > off-topic > migration" submenu? I may know better than to ever select the mostly-useless "This question belongs on another site" option (except for moving stuff to/from meta, that is), but to a less experienced / jaded user who's just following the descriptions, it may seem like the right choice.

@IlmariKaronen: I think you make a decent point, but perhaps the best way of implementing this would be just to add a moderator check to the full-site method. That is, provide users with exactly the same interface that would be provided on a non-beta site, but when suitably voted instead of being migrated it would be shown to a moderator.

@figlesquidge: That wouldn't help too much, since the non-mod migration feature is IME pretty useless on non-beta sites too. It works OK for meta <-> main site migrations, and it may sometimes work for the occasional pairs of sites that have scopes close enough to both generate lots of migrations and have a large community overlap (e.g. math <-> MO, ELU <-> ELL or, potentially, crypto <-> security)...

...but otherwise it tends to do pretty poorly, both because a) the menu length is limited to something like 5 migration targets per site, which means much of the "long tail" of off-topic questions can still only be migrated by mods, and because b) even when a non-mod migration path exists, without a lot of community overlap there's a good chance that users on site A will vote to migrate questions to site B that just get closed there. (That's why e.g. non-mod migration from SO to SF is no longer allowed.)

I think it's been well over a year since I last voted to migrate any post on any SE site (except maybe for some main <-> meta migration). I used to flag a lot more posts for mod migration, but nowadays I usually just vote to close and leave a comment suggesting that the OP should re-ask the question on the appropriate site. It seems to be the most effective way.

@Shog9 That scope finding issue might have been appropriate when 90 day betas were envisioned. But we have pretty clear agreement which questions belong on crypto, security or stackoverflow. In any case having 5 votes for migration seems like a better idea for figuring out if a question belongs here instead of unilateral migration by a mod.
